# PM2 cannot find module /home/ubuntu/{module_name}

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, pm2

I have been using PM2 to run a Node.js app on an EC2 instance for a while now. However, it crashed today and I can't get it to restart with pm2.
It would be great if someone could help me get it up and running again.

When I `cd` into the project directory and call my `npm start` script, that works fine. But when I try to run `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js` I'm getting the error below (PalauCmsSql is the name of my project).

```
0|PalauCmsSql  | Error: Cannot find module '/home/ubuntu/PalauCmsSql'
0|PalauCmsSql  |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
0|PalauCmsSql  |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
0|PalauCmsSql  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js:33:23)
0|PalauCmsSql  |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
0|PalauCmsSql  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
0|PalauCmsSql  |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
0|PalauCmsSql  |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
0|PalauCmsSql  |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:75:12)
0|PalauCmsSql  |     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
0|PalauCmsSql  |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
0|PalauCmsSql  |   requireStack: []
0|PalauCmsSql  | }
PM2            | App [PalauCmsSql:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
```

My `ecosystem.config.js` looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'PalauCmsSql',
      cwd: '/home/ubuntu/PalauCmsSql',
      script: 'npm',
      args: 'start',
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production',
      },
    },
    {
      name: 'PalauCmsSqlDevelopment',
      cwd: '/home/ubuntu/PalauCmsSql',
      script: 'npm',
      args: 'development',
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: 'development',
        PORT: 1338
      }
    }
  ],
};
```

I double checked that the path '/home/ubuntu/PalauCmsSql' is correct and it is.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could point out why I'm getting this error. Thanks in advance!